# Skip a subgoal while proving in Isabelle

Tags: proof, isabelle, theorem-proving, isar

I am trying to prove a theorem but got stuck at a subgoal (that I prefer to skip and prove later). How can I skip this and prove the others ?

First, I tried `oops` and `sorry` but they both abort the entire proof (instead of the only subgoal). I also tried to put the subgoal into a dummy lemma (assuming proven with `sorry`) then using it (`apply (rule [my dummy lemma])`) but it applies the dummy lemma to every other subgoals (not only the first one).

Comment: I feel like some information is missing in this question.

Comment: I agree that a minimal example would help a long way to make clear what is asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It mostly depends on whether you are using the archaic (sorry for that ;)) apply-style or proper structured Isar for proving. I will give a small example to cover both styles. Assume you wanted to prove

```
lemma "A & B"
```

Where `A` and `B` just serve as placeholders for potentially huge formulas.

As structured proof you would do something like:

```
proof
  show "A" sorry
next
  show "B" sorry
qed
```

I.e., in this style you can use `sorry` to omit proofs for subgoals.

In apply-style you could do

```
apply (rule conjI)
defer -- "moves the first subgoal to the last position"
apply (*proof for subgoal "B"*)
apply (*proof for subgoal "A"*)
```

There is also the apply-style command `prefer n` which moves subgoal `n` to the front.

Comment: Thank you. That perfectly answers to my question. Indeed, I am trying to prove the theorem in "old"/apply style.